# Mongoose problen find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a query using lookup (populate) in mongoose, the query should give me some matches for the "name" property but it returns whatever, that is, the result of the query is not precise, sometimes it searches something and in others it does nothing

I have the following:

```
const products = await Product.aggregate([
                { $match: { isActive: true, name: { $regex: query.keyword, $options: "i" } } },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "stores",
                        localField: "store",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "store_details"
                    }
                }
            ])
                .skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize || 1)
                .limit(pageSize || 36)
//return [], without values
```

I tried .populate, but I need more information on how lookup does it, which breaks everything down.

I have several documents in the "store" collection with the word "pack" in the "name" field but the code I show above only returns 1 single item (1/10). I would like to know how I can achieve the appropriate query so that it is (10/10).

Basically what I want to achieve is that with a keyword for example keyword="pack" you can get all the documents with "pack" within the "name" field

I thank you in advance for any help and guidance you can offer me.

Comment: I may be wrong, but that doesn’t look like mongoose to me

Comment: That query seems to work in the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2NDaq3z5Is2

Comment: @Joe Thank you for taking a moment of your time to help me, for some reason it doesn't always work and it doesn't work that way for all documents, I have several documents with the word "pack" but it still returns 1 document, I don't understand why and still I'm still looking for the correct way to make it work, I have exactly the code shown above and in the example you gave me it works fine except for my query

Comment: try without the skip and limit, those aren't going to be stable without a sort anyway

Comment: @Joe ok I'll try